# Ошибка при выдаче роли (Дискорд бот)

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py, discord-api

Есть бот который выдает роли когда нажимаешь на эмозди вот так: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но по не известной мне причине, бот выдает мне ошибку когда я пытаюсь выдать себе роль нажав на эмозди: `AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'roles'")` или же когда я забираю роль: `AttributeError("'NoneType' object has no attribute 'remove_roles'")`

Код:

`

```
import discord

from discord import utils

import config


class MyClient(discord.Client):
async def on_ready(self):
    print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))

async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
    if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id)  # получаем объект канала
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)  # получаем объект сообщения
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members,
                           id=payload.user_id)  # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию

        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji)  # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji])  # объект выбранной роли (если есть)

            if(len([i for i in member.roles if i and i.id not in config.EXCROLES])):
                await member.add_roles(role)
                print('[SUCCESS] User {0.display_name} has been granted with role {1.name}'.format(member, role))
            else:
                await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, member)
                print('[ERROR] Too many roles for user {0.display_name}'.format(member))

        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))

async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
    channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id)  # получаем объект канала
    message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)  # получаем объект сообщения
    member = utils.get(message.guild.members,
                       id=payload.user_id)  # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию

    try:
        emoji = str(payload.emoji)  # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
        role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji])  # объект выбранной роли (если есть)

        await member.remove_roles(role)
        print('[SUCCESS] Role {1.name} has been remove for user {0.display_name}'.format(member, role))

    except KeyError as e:
        print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
    except Exception as e:
        print(repr(e))


# RUN
client = MyClient()
client.run(config.TOKEN)`
```

Это основной код а вот код конфига:

```
TOKEN = 'ODIzNTk5MzUyMDg1MDg2MjQ4.YFjKqw.GMHHZpEF3IAWTxnLdsQBnU8Rt2Y'

POST_ID = 823603055777546280

ROLES = {
'1️⃣': 823509591592796171, # 1 pos
'2️⃣': 823509534114709545, # 2 pos
'3️⃣': 823509444633690144, # 3 pos
'4️⃣': 823509286012583966, # 4 pos
'5️⃣': 823515028383858699 # 5 pos
}

EXCROLES = ()
```

За ранее, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Я сам долго парился, в общем, если кому нужен код, который делал хауди хо!, то я его доделал, вот полностью готовый код, постараемся вместе разобраться.

Они зачем-то добавляют отступы перед каждой строчкой, просто удали их и должно заработать

Если не заработает, то я ещё установил это:

> py -3 -m pip install -U discord.py

Я не знаю за что оно отвечает, но оно видимо обновляет дискорд до последней версии.

```
import discord
from discord import utils
 
import config



class MyClient(discord.Client):
# Проверка готовности бота
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
# Добавление роли с помощью реакций
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
            channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем объект канала
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем объект сообщения
            member = payload.member # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию
            print(member)
 
            try:
                emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
                role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) # объект выбранной роли (если есть)
            
                if(len([i for i in member.roles if i and i.id not in config.EXCROLES]) <= config.MAX_ROLES_PER_USER):
                    await member.add_roles(role)
                    print('[SUCCESS] User {0.display_name} has been granted with role {1.name}'.format(member, role))
                else:
                    await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, member)
                    print('[ERROR] Too many roles for user {0.display_name}'.format(member))
            
            except KeyError as e:
                print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
            except Exception as e:
                print(repr(e))
 
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем id канала
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем id сообщения
        user_id = payload.user_id # по сути эта херня не нужна, но на всякий случай не трож
        member = await (await client.fetch_guild(payload.guild_id)).fetch_member(payload.user_id) №
        print(member, user_id)
 
        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) # объект выбранной роли (если есть)
    
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print('[SUCCESS] Role {1.name} has been remove for user {0.display_name}'.format(member, role))
 

    введите сюда код
        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))
 
# RUN
client = MyClient()
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0):

Доброй ночи, исправил вам код, попробуйте

```
    import discord
    
    from discord import utils
    
    import config
    
    intents = discord.Intents.all()
    intents.members = True
    
    class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
    
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
            channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id)  # получаем объект канала
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)  # получаем объект сообщения
            member = utils.get(message.guild.members,
                               id=payload.user_id)  # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию
    
            try:
                emoji = str(payload.emoji)  # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
                role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji])  # объект выбранной роли (если есть)
    
                if(len([i for i in member.roles if i and i.id not in config.EXCROLES])):
                    await member.add_roles(role)
                    print('[SUCCESS] User {0.display_name} has been granted with role {1.name}'.format(member, role))
                else:
                    await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, member)
                    print('[ERROR] Too many roles for user {0.display_name}'.format(member))
    
            except KeyError as e:
                print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
            except Exception as e:
                print(repr(e))
    
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id)  # получаем объект канала
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id)  # получаем объект сообщения
        member = utils.get(message.guild.members,
                           id=payload.user_id)  # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию
    
        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji)  # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji])  # объект выбранной роли (если есть)
    
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print('[SUCCESS] Role {1.name} has been remove for user {0.display_name}'.format(member, role))
    
        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))
    
    
    client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
    
    
    
    client = MyClient(intents = discord.Intents.all())
    client.run(config.TOKEN)`
```

Answer (score 0):

Я чуть правил код, и теперь оно работает в 2022

```
import discord
from discord import utils
import config

class MyClient(discord.Client):
# Проверка готовности бота
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as {0}!'.format(self.user))
# Добавление роли с помощью реакций
    async def on_raw_reaction_add(self, payload):
        if payload.message_id == config.POST_ID:
            channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем объект канала
            message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем объект сообщения
            member = payload.member # получаем объект пользователя который поставил реакцию
            print(member)
 
            try:
                emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
                role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) # объект выбранной роли (если есть)
            
                if(len([i for i in member.roles if i and i.id not in config.EXCROLES]) <= config.MAX_ROLES_PER_USER):
                    await member.add_roles(role)
                    print('[SUCCESS] User {0.display_name} has been granted with role {1.name}'.format(member, role))
                else:
                    await message.remove_reaction(payload.emoji, member)
                    print('[ERROR] Too many roles for user {0.display_name}'.format(member))
            
            except KeyError as e:
                print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
            except Exception as e:
                print(repr(e))
 
    async def on_raw_reaction_remove(self, payload):
        channel = self.get_channel(payload.channel_id) # получаем id канала
        message = await channel.fetch_message(payload.message_id) # получаем id сообщения
        user_id = payload.user_id # по сути эта херня не нужна, но на всякий случай не трож
        member = await (await client.fetch_guild(payload.guild_id)).fetch_member(payload.user_id)
        print(member, user_id)
 
        try:
            emoji = str(payload.emoji) # эмоджик который выбрал юзер
            role = utils.get(message.guild.roles, id=config.ROLES[emoji]) # объект выбранной роли (если есть)
    
            await member.remove_roles(role)
            print('[SUCCESS] Role {1.name} has been remove for user {0.display_name}'.format(member, role))
 
        except KeyError as e:
            print('[ERROR] KeyError, no role found for ' + emoji)
        except Exception as e:
            print(repr(e))
 
# RUN
client = MyClient()
client.run(config.TOKEN)
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]